# SQL return all id's from 1 table and only ones that don't match from another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables: `#tmptable1` and `#tmptable2`.  These tables have an ID to uniquely identify each record.

I want to return all records from table 1, but I only want to return the records from table 2 that aren't in table 1

I want this done in 1 query.

Thanks!

Comment: You might give us the structure... could help here...

Comment: #tmptable1 contains a.id
#tmptable2 contains b.id

There are some of the same ID's between a and b and I want to return all a.id's but only b.id's that are not the same as a.id's

Comment: Just to be clear are there additional columns as well as the `id` ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM '#tmptable1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM  '#tmptable2' WHERE 
    ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM #tmptable1 WHERE ID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Will this work if the rows are different but could contain the same ID's. 1 column is different at the end.

Answer (score 3):

If all the other fields and data of the two tables is identical you could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM #tmptable1
UNION
SELECT * FROM #tmptable2
```

UNION *without* the ALL modifier removes duplicates.

Comment: But that will still bring back 2 rows if the same id is in both tables and it has different values for the other columns. (unless of course there *are* no additional columns)

Comment: @Martin Smith: True -- that's why the "if" in the first line of my post is important.

Comment: @Martin Smith: No problem, it's a good point worth emphasizing.

Comment: They are in fact different. The last column contains a different note so I need just when the ID's are the same...?

Comment: @anicolais: Then go with @Martin Smith's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what is it that you want to get in the results, but `UNION` selects distinct values, so you won't have duplicate values (values from #tmptable2 that already exist in #tmptable1).

```
SELECT * FROM #tmptable1
UNION
SELECT * FROM #tmptable2
```

Anyways, these records are records from #tmptable2 that aren't in #tmptable1.

```
SELECT * FROM #tmptable2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM #tmptable1
```

Comment: Minus is Oracle only and the OP wants rows not just ids.

Comment: @Matrin Thanks for noticing that. My bad. Fixed it.

Comment: You would still need to include all records from `#tmptable1` somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID FROM #tmptable1
UNION
SELECT ID FROM #tmptable2
```

The `UNION` operator will automatically remove duplicates.